# WatchService is there any build in api for timeout if not event happens in directory

Tags: java

I would like to ask you a question about `WatchService`. So I have code which is renaming specific file when it appears in the directory. But I would like to set up the timeout for `WatchService` running for like a 2 minutes if nothing happens inside of directory.

But from what I read. There is timeout, but only for sleep before starting monitoring directory.

So the code looks like that:

```
try {
            WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            Paths.get(dirPath).register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

            WatchKey key;
            while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    String fileName = event.context().toString();
                    if (isPdfFile(fileName)) {
                        consumer.accept(dirPath + fileName);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                key.reset();

            }
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {}
```

Or is there other workaround for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a timeout while waiting for an event you need to use [`WatchService.poll(long,TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#poll(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). If I understand your question correctly, you want to wait up to two minutes, short-circuiting on the first matching event. In this case you'll need to keep track of how long you've actually waited so far and timeout for the remaining duration. Otherwise you'll wait two minutes every loop or worse just drop out of the method on the first non-matching event. I believe the following (untested) code should work similar to what you want:

```
public static Optional<Path> watch(Path directory, Predicate<? super Path> filter)
        throws IOException {
    try (WatchService service = directory.getFileSystem().newWatchService()) {
        directory.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        long timeout = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(2L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        while (timeout > 0L) {
            final long start = System.nanoTime();
            WatchKey key = service.poll(timeout, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            if (key != null) {
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    Path context = (Path) event.context();
                    if (filter.test(context)) {
                        return Optional.of(directory.resolve(context));
                    }
                }
                key.reset();
                // Accounts for the above execution time. If you don't want that you
                // can move this to before the "for" loop.
                timeout -= System.nanoTime() - start;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

This code also closes the `WatchService` when done using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). It also returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) rather than using a `Consumer`. The `Predicate` would do the same thing as `isPdfFile(...)`. I did it this way because it makes the method independent (which is good for an example) but you can continue using `isPdfFile` and `Consumer` if you want. Using the method might look something like:

```
Path dir = ...;
watch(dir, file -> isPdfFile(file)).ifPresent(/* do something */);
```

---

As an aside, your code uses [`take()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#take()) and checks if it returns `null`. That method should never return `null` as it waits until it an event is available. In other words, it returns a `WatchKey` or throws.